# Getting 'commentcontent' via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm building up an ajax function that grabs the info needed to send into the database than print it out on the page. Only it grabs the streamid but not the commentcontent. I can see this in firebug under the post parameters. The strange thing is, I've used the same method for my main status updates and just changed the id's so they don't conflict.

Most would say there is no value in the commentcontent..but that would be the users inserted comment, and their is no value on my main status updates..So I'm rubbing my head thinking, where am I going wrong?

FORM

```
 <form id='mycommentform' method='POST'  class='form_statusinput'>
    <input type='hidden'  name='streamid' id='streamid' value='".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."'>
    <input class='text' name='commentcontent' id='commentcontent' placeholder='Say something' autocomplete='off'>
    <input type='submit' id='button' value='Feed'>
    </form>
    </div>
```

AJAX

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#mycommentform").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var streamid = $("#streamid").val();
    var commentcontent = $("#commentcontent").val();

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "comment_add.php",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    data: {  streamid:  streamid, commentcontent: commentcontent}, 
    success: function(response){ 
     $("#commentcontent").val(""); 
    $("#commentaddid").html("<div class='stream_comment_holder' style='display:none;' id='comment_holder_"+response['streamitem_id']+"'><div id='comment_list_"+response['streamitem_id']+"'></div></div>");
    }
    });
    return false
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: I don't think it is related but you may want to change `class="text"` to `type="text"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always need to quote your data, so changing it to: `{  'streamid':  streamid, 'commentcontent': commentcontent}` should probably fix your issue
After some discussion, we found out
 `var commentcontent = $(this).children('#commentcontent ').val();`
 fixed the issue

Comment: Or it might be what hsalama said ^^ (you should still quote the data though)

Comment: Still the same issue with both changed.

Comment: Are you sure `commentcontent` is unique? try `var commentcontent = $(this).children(':nth-child(2)').val();`

Comment: It is. Which is weird. I'd tried your code and when submitting a comment, it doesn't even show the commentcontent within the post parameters.

Comment: var commentcontent = $(this).children('#commentcontent ').val(); Was the key. Thank you.

Comment: That probably means your id is used somewhere else on your page

Comment: I'd tried the find in dreamweaver with no result. But yeah. Yet again something simple. I shall accept your answer if you update it with the code you provided. Thank you for your help and time. I certainly won't make this minor mistake in a hurry.